# Fill select options with object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I am reusing a function that returns an object of arrays like such:

```
75: {id: 75, table_no: 40, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null, …}
76: {id: 76, table_no: 41, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null, …}
77: {id: 77, table_no: 44, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null, …}
78: {id: 78, table_no: 45, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null, …}
79: {id: 79, table_no: 42, capacity: 6, shape: "large_rectangle", time: null, …}
80: {id: 80, table_no: 43, capacity: 6, shape: "large_rectangle", time: null, …}
__proto__: Object
```

As You can see in each array there is an id and table no, i want to use these values to fill a `<select>` input. I have tried everything, map(), for loops, `$.each()`. I can't even display `result.length` as it returns undefined.

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
  data: data
})
.done((result) => {
  if(result) {
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(result);
    var select = $('#table');

    result.map(item => {
      console.log(item);
    })
  }
})
```

PHP

```
function getPremiseTablesByArea($connection, $id) {
  $tables = NULL;
  $query = "SELECT t.id, t.number, t.capacity, t.shape, t.time_duration, t.joinable,
                   t.area, t.baby_friendly, t.premise_code, a.name, p.name
            FROM tables t
            JOIN areas a ON a.id = t.area
            JOIN premises p ON p.code = t.premise_code WHERE t.area = ?";
  if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $number, $capacity, $shape, $time, $joinable, $area, $babyFriendly, $premiseCode, $areaName, $premiseName);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      $tables[$id]['id'] = $id;
      $tables[$id]['table_no'] = $number;
      $tables[$id]['capacity'] = $capacity;
      $tables[$id]['shape'] = $shape;
      $tables[$id]['time'] = $time;
      $tables[$id]['joinable'] = $joinable;
      $tables[$id]['area'] = $area;
      $tables[$id]['baby_friendly'] = $babyFriendly;
      $tables[$id]['premise_code'] = $premiseCode;
      $tables[$id]['area_name'] = $areaName;
      $tables[$id]['premise_name'] = $premiseName;
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
  return $tables;
}
```

Comment: Modified tag from java to javascript. No worries regarding the confusion, it's unfortunately all too common.

Comment: As the result returned from the ajax call is empty. Can you check why that function is returning empty.

Comment: @Jason it was just a mis-click thankfully haha

Comment: If "result" is an object and not an array, well you can't use map or any of the array functions.  Is there a reason it's not an array?

Comment: @James I'm not even sure why it isn't an array, let me edit the question and show the PHP function.

Comment: You cannot use map on object. If input is coming in object form, then you can use Object.values(result).map(...) to resolve this issue. But I would recommend first try to get result in array format instead of object. If that is not possible, then use 'Object.values' approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `object.values()` and `forEach`

```js
select=document.getElementById("select")
   
 obj={0:{id: 75, table_no: 40, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null}, 1:{id: 76, table_no: 41, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null}, 2:{id: 77, table_no: 44, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null}, 3:{id: 78, table_no: 45, capacity: 4, shape: "circle", time: null}, 4:{id: 79, table_no: 42, capacity: 6, shape: "large_rectangle", time: null}, 5:{id: 80, table_no: 43, capacity: 6, shape: "large_rectangle", time: null,}}

  Object.values(obj).forEach(o=>{
  var option = document.createElement("option")
  option.text= o.table_no
  option.value = o.id
  select.appendChild(option)})
```

```html
<select id="select">  
</select>
```

Comment: When I console log this it returns `0: {id: 75, tablenum: 40}
1: {id: 76, tablenum: 41}
2: {id: 77, tablenum: 44}
3: {id: 78, tablenum: 45}
4: {id: 79, tablenum: 42}
5: {id: 80, tablenum: 43}`

Comment: yes isn't that what you want ? you want to extract the id and table_no?

Comment: Oh sorry, let me try that then!

Comment: to assign the values to your table just iterate with a foreach or  you could do it directly in the map function

Comment: `results=Object.values(result).map(o=>({
              select.append("<option />").val(o.id)
            }));` isnt working :(

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example using forEach let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much I have a massive headache

Comment: You're Welcome and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You could change your PHP to return an array of objects:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $tables[$id]['id'] = $id;
  $tables[$id]['table_no'] = $number;
  $tables[$id]['capacity'] = $capacity;
  $tables[$id]['shape'] = $shape;
  $tables[$id]['time'] = $time;
  $tables[$id]['joinable'] = $joinable;
  $tables[$id]['area'] = $area;
  $tables[$id]['baby_friendly'] = $babyFriendly;
  $tables[$id]['premise_code'] = $premiseCode;
  $tables[$id]['area_name'] = $areaName;
  $tables[$id]['premise_name'] = $premiseName;
}
```

becomes

```
$tables = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

(However your field names will be slightly different, if they need to be identical use AS to alias the field names in your query).

Now you are free to use map on the resulting javascript array.